# merge в Python: не работает при разных типах данных

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

объединяю 2 датафрейма, и у них разные типы данных в столбцах, хотя dtypes показывает, что все норм.
Пример кода:

```
data = {'col1': ['val1','val2', 'val3'], 
        'col2': ['123','text', 345]}
data2 = {'col3': ['val1','val2', 'val3'], 
        'col4': ['312','text', '345']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

специально меняю тип всего столбца, чтобы значение 345 в col2 стало строкой.

```
df['col2'].astype('str', copy=False)
```

мерджу

```
pd.merge(df, df2, left_on='col2', right_on='col4', how='outer')
```

Но все равно не совмещает 1 строку:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
0   val1    123     NaN     NaN
1   val2    text    val2    text
2   val3    345     NaN     NaN
3   NaN     NaN     val1    312
4   NaN     NaN     val3    345
```

2 и 4 строки должны быть совмещены. Как этого добиться?

В работе датафреймы с сотнями тысячами строк.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Естественно, изменённые данные нужно записать обратно в колонку, вы же результат никуда не записываете:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype('str')
```

P.S. Я убрал `copy=False`, не могу точно сказать, почему у вас с ним не работает без присваивания, но использование этого параметра в документации сопровождается предупреждением и лучше с ним не экспериментировать. Вообще, операции через точку в `Pandas` часто работают на копии данных, поэтому лучше все присвоения делать в явном виде, не используя изменения "на месте" (`inplace`).

Другой вариант - указать сразу тип данных в явном виде, чтобы потом не преобразовывать:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype='str')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, dtype='str')
```

Comment: параметр copy=False указывает на перезапись датафрейма. Поэтому не нужно перезаписывать столбец

Comment: @danilfg И тем не менее, если записать нормально данные обратно, то так работает. Вообще все варианты с `inplace` заменами будут выпилены из `Pandas` в ближайшем будущем, ибо они частый источник всякой непонятной фигни. И в данном случае тоже стоит примечание в документации, что надо осторожно этим параметром пользоваться. Не могу точно сказать, почему это не работает, но лучше так не делать.

Comment: @danilfg, если не перезаписывать явно DataFrame/Series результатом `.astype(..., copy=False)`, то исходный DataFrame/Series останется неизменным

Answer (score 2):

В общем разобрался, нужно было вот так менять тип:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype(str)
```

И все стало нормальным.

Comment: это никак не поможет если вы не сохранили результат обратно в `df['col2']`

Comment: Не знаю, какая у вас версия `Pandas`, в Google Colab это точно так же не работает без присвоения

Comment: @MaxU, исправил)